# Hibernate - NoSuchMethodError - Sessionfactory

Tags: java, hibernate

Добрый день.
После заполнения формы валится такая вот ошибка:

```
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces 
Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
.......
at com.greef.utils.DbUtil.<clinit>(DbUtil.java:22)
at com.greef.dao.impl.UserDao.create(UserDao.java:24)
at com.greef.beans.UserBean.register(UserBean.java:85)
.......
```

### DbUtil

---

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder= new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
    sessionFactory= cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```

### UserDao

---

```
       try {
        session = DbUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
.....
```

### UserBean

---

```
public void register(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(getUserName());
    user.setPswd(getUserPswd());
    user.setPswdConfirm(getUserPswdConfirm());
    user.setEmail(getUserEmail());

    Factory factory = Factory.getInstance();
    UserDao userDao = factory.getUserDao();
    try {
        userDao.create(user);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Из-за чего она может сыпаться? Как с ней бороться?

Comment: Версии гибернейта(4 и 3) конфликтуют скорее всего, нужно смотреть зависимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема заключалась в отсутствии jar файлов hibernate в WEB-INF/lib, после добавление их туда через project structure -> artifacts все благополучно задеплоилось и заработало